# Yii2 Left Join in query builder

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables, the `report_details` and the `name`. In the `report_details` table, I have for and from which is an id that is related to the table `name`. What is the proper syntax in Yii2 to get both the for and from the column on the `name` table? This is my query so far...

```
 $query = new yii\db\Query;
                $query->select('report_details.reference_no, report_details.subject, report_details.doc_for, report_details.doc_from, report_details.doc_date, report_details.doc_name, report_details.drawer_id, report_details.user_id, name.name_id, name.position, name.fname, name.mname, name.lname')
                    ->from('report_details')
                    ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'name', 'report_details.doc_for = name.name_id')
                    ->where(['report_details.reference_no' => $model->reference_no]);
                $results = $query->all();
```

Comment: you are getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

you could use   `->leftJoin(    )`

```
  $query = new yii\db\Query;
            $query->select('report_details.reference_no, report_details.subject, 
                          report_details.doc_for, report_details.doc_from, 
                          report_details.doc_date, report_details.doc_name, 
                          report_details.drawer_id, report_details.user_id,
                          name.name_id, name.position, name.fname, name.mname, name.lname')
                ->from('report_details')
                ->leftJoin( 'name', 'report_details.doc_for = name.name_id')
                ->where(['report_details.reference_no' => $model->reference_no]);
  $results = $query->all();
```